# In a .net core 3.0 BackgroundService app, why is my configuration object empty when running as service, but not as console app?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, windows-services

I have a .net Core 3.0 BackgroundService application that works fine when running in console mode, but once i deploy as a service the configuration object that should be loaded from appsettings.json is empty.  What gives?

**Program.cs**

```
public class Program
{
    public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var hostbuilder = new HostBuilder()
            .UseWindowsService()
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                config
                .SetBasePath(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location))
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
            })
            .ConfigureLogging(
                options => options.AddFilter<EventLogLoggerProvider>(level => level >= LogLevel.Information))
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<Importer>().Configure<EventLogSettings>(config =>
                {
                    config.LogName = "Application";
                    config.SourceName = "Importer";
                });
            });
#if (DEBUG)
        await hostbuilder.RunConsoleAsync();
#else
        await hostbuilder.RunAsServiceAsync();
#endif
    }
}
```

**Extension Method for IhostBuilder to run service**

```
public static class ServiceBaseLifetimeHostExtensions
{
    public static IHostBuilder UseServiceBaseLifetime(this IHostBuilder hostBuilder)
    {
        return hostBuilder.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) => services.AddSingleton<IHostLifetime, ServiceBaseLifetime>());
    }

    public static Task RunAsServiceAsync(this IHostBuilder hostBuilder, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        return hostBuilder.UseServiceBaseLifetime().Build().RunAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

**ServiceBaseLifetime class to handle service lifecycle**

```
public class ServiceBaseLifetime : ServiceBase, IHostLifetime
{
    private readonly TaskCompletionSource<object> _delayStart = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

    public ServiceBaseLifetime(IHostApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
    {
        ApplicationLifetime = applicationLifetime ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(applicationLifetime));
    }

    private IHostApplicationLifetime ApplicationLifetime { get; }

    public Task WaitForStartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        cancellationToken.Register(() => _delayStart.TrySetCanceled());
        ApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(Stop);

        new Thread(Run).Start(); // Otherwise this would block and prevent IHost.StartAsync from finishing.
        return _delayStart.Task;
    }

    private void Run()
    {
        try
        {
            Run(this); // This blocks until the service is stopped.
            _delayStart.TrySetException(new InvalidOperationException("Stopped without starting"));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _delayStart.TrySetException(ex);
        }
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Stop();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    // Called by base.Run when the service is ready to start.
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        _delayStart.TrySetResult(null);
        base.OnStart(args);
    }

    // Called by base.Stop. This may be called multiple times by service Stop, ApplicationStopping, and StopAsync.
    // That's OK because StopApplication uses a CancellationTokenSource and prevents any recursion.
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        ApplicationLifetime.StopApplication();
        base.OnStop();
    }
}
```

**The actual implementation of the service is irrelevant other than the constructor, which takes the logger and configuration through DI.**

```
private readonly ILogger<Importer> _logger;
private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

public Importer(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<Importer> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _configuration = configuration;
}

protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    _logger.LogInformation($"Why is {_configuration["Key1"]} empty?");
}
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{
    "Key1":"some value"
}
```

When i run through debug the console app starts up and runs and logs and has the configuration loaded from appsettings.  When i deploy as a service the configuration object is empty.

**Notes: The appsettings file is being read, i can tell this by changing the name of it and it throws an exception for file not found.  The appsettings file is also not empty.**

Answer (score 1):

My issue appears to be some kind of async race condition problem (I am guessing, not positive). The first tick through `ExecuteAsync` the configuration is not loaded, but the second time through it is. I had the service dying if it encountered that exception, so i never got it to tick a second time.

Comment: I'm stumbling over this right now. Did you find a solution to avoid the race condition?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and is worthy of a refactor

Create a strongly typed model to hold the desired settings

```
public class ImporterSettings {
    public string Key1 { get; set; }
}
```

Refactor hosted service to depend on the settings since tightly coupling services to `IConfiguration` is a code smell in my opinion

```
private readonly ILogger<Importer> _logger;
private readonly ImporterSettnigs settings;

public Importer(ImporterSettnigs settings, ILogger<Importer> logger) {
    _logger = logger;
    this.settings = settings;
}

protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) {
    _logger.LogInformation($"This is Key1: {settings.Key1}");
}
```

Now properly configure start up to use the provided configuration

```
public class Program {
    public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args) {
        var hostbuilder = new HostBuilder()
            .UseWindowsService()
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) => {
                var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
                config
                    .SetBasePath(path)
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
            })
            .ConfigureLogging(
                options => options.AddFilter<EventLogLoggerProvider>(level => 
                    level >= LogLevel.Information)
            )
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) => {
                //get settings from app configuration.
                ImporterSettings settings = hostContext.Configuration.Get<ImporterSettings>();

                services
                    .AddSingleton(settings) //add to service collection
                    .AddHostedService<Importer>()
                    .Configure<EventLogSettings>(config => {
                        config.LogName = "Application";
                        config.SourceName = "Importer";
                    });
            });
#if (DEBUG)
        await hostbuilder.RunConsoleAsync();
#else
        await hostbuilder..Build().RunAsync();
#endif
    }
}
```

Comment: Refactored, code is cleaner.  Still same issue though.

Comment: I appreciate your help.  I tried it without the `RunAsServiceAsync` extension call and used the code from that article and i get the same result.  Works locally as console app, not as service.  I think it is reading in the file correctly though, as i can rename the file to `testfile123.json` and change the code to use that file name and it will not throw the file not found exception.  If it wasn't finding the file then it would throw that exception.

Comment: I am using reflection to find the executing assembly path and i can throw out some logging statements showing that the path being checked is the path i want.

Comment: Ok in that case I'll keep digging.

Comment: @NickD while debugging windows service put a break point in the `ConfigureServices` and inspect the configuration there

Comment: I feel like an idiot, this appears to be some kind of async race condition problem.  The first tick through execute the configuration is not loaded, but the second time through it is.  I had the service dying if it encountered that exception, so i never got it to tick a second time.  I still dont fully understand why its happening, but at least its working.  Thanks for your time.